# I can't really get the point of the problem because I don't program on assembler

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to find the max of array

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int n = 4;
int res = 0;
__asm {
        mov ecx, n
        xor eax, eax
        xor esi, esi
        mov esi, 0
        mov eax, a[esi]
cycle:  cmp a[esi], eax
        jle pass
        mov eax, a[esi] ; when second number of array moves to EAX it somehow becomes 33554432
pass:   inc esi
        loop cycle
        mov res, eax
```

I already tried xor eax, eax and add eax, a[esi]

Comment: What's the size of the `int`? You probably need to increase `esi` by 4 (or size of int)

Comment: if you are not an expert in assembly language then you should avoid inline assembly, use real assembly for a task like this...

Comment: ints are signed so you want to initialize your register to the minimum value number which is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
        mov ecx, n
        xor eax, eax
        xor esi, esi
        mov esi, 0
        mov eax, a[esi]
cycle:  cmp a[esi], eax
        jle pass
        mov eax, a[esi] 
pass:   add esi,4 ; size of int should go here
        loop cycle
        mov res, eax
```